# Check if clang is installed (windows)

Tags: clang

I am a windows novice and I have no idea how to check if clang is installed on my machine.

Any quick solutions?

Comment: I forgot to mention I don't have access to powershell or cmd.

Comment: check if it is located in the `PATH`?